# PayPal Sandbox: Preconfigured Account Creation Failed error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to create a paypal sandbox test account using preconfigured account method but when i create the account it is showing the following error:

> Some information is incorrect or missing. Please correct your entries
> and try again.
>
> * Account Creation Failed !!!

I given all information and most are automatically creating by paypal but i dont know what is missing. It is not giving any hints on error.

Please help !

Comment: This is a PayPal bug. Please contact PayPal at https://www.paypal.com/mts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. PayPal are aware of it and are working on fixing it.

For more information: https://www.x.com/node/301333

Comment: +1 - This was helpful. I thought I was missing something and spent an hour trying to figure out what it was. It turns out it's just paypal being useless.

Comment: -1, because I posted the exact same thing 10 hours earlier and it's not a programming question.

Comment: @Robert Sure, it may not be a programming question, but it is related, and SO was the first place I looked to see if anybody was experiencing the same issue. Contacting PayPal also doesn't offer much assistance, especially to those less knowledgeable of where to look, hence why I posted an answer with the information from PayPal as that "answered" the question. No beef, either way.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but the problem with PayPal's site is still the same. After trying and trying, I found that all I had to was enter a first name and a last name, even though it says those fields are optional. Hopefully this helps someone.